# Find a function for well form brackets using generating functions

Tags: generating-functions

How to find a function for calculating the number of well form brackets (for "n" pairs of brackets) using generating function? This is a probably a routine problem for some people, but I haven't got any resource on generating function.

Comment: What are well formed brackets?  A series of parentheses that have the same number of opens as closes?  Wouldn't that just be $\binom {2n}{n}$ for a string $2n$ long?

Comment: A must read on generating functions is Wilf's book www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf

Comment: @Ross: Probably it means that you at any stage must have more left than right brackets, in which case the answer is given by the Catalan numbers.

Comment: @Hans:  I think you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Hans Lundmark is right, you could see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_numbers) on the Catalan numbers, where the generating function is given under "Proof of the Formula"  There are also many references in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000108)